# Renaming the x ticks / Seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

So unfortunately I am facing the problem right now, that I plotted two subplots next to each other but would like to get the full name of the months instead of the number (this happened because in the data frame the months are given as a number) on the x-axis[![enter image description here]  Can anybody give me advice how to change it?

Following the code:
'''

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14,6))    
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
             'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']    
sns.set_style('darkgrid')   
custom_palette=['orange','purple']   
sns.set_palette(custom_palette)   
sns.countplot(x='month',hue='year', data=continent_3[continent_3["is_booking"] == 1], ax=ax1)    
sns.pointplot(x='month',y='is_booking',hue='year', ci=None, data=continent_3, ax=ax2)    
ax1.set(xlabel = 'Month', ylabel = 'Bookings')   
ax2.set(xlabel = 'Month', ylabel = 'Bookings')   
ax1.set_title('Absoulute Number of Bookings', y=1.03, fontsize=17)   
ax2.set_title('Conversion Rate', y=1.03, fontsize=17)   
ax1.get_legend().remove()   
ax2.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.85), ncol=1)   
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.2)
```

'''

Thank you in advance. 
[image]

Comment: you can use ax.set_xticklabels, if you need more help I suggest you to post the code you used to generate the plot

Comment: Hey unfortunately it did not work, but I just posted the code

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `set_xticklabels` method from [matplotlib.axes.Axes](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html).

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(14,6))    
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
             'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']    
sns.set_style('darkgrid')   
custom_palette=['orange','purple']   
sns.set_palette(custom_palette)   
sns.countplot(x='month',hue='year', data=continent_3[continent_3["is_booking"] == 1], ax=ax1)    
sns.pointplot(x='month',y='is_booking',hue='year', ci=None, data=continent_3, ax=ax2)    
ax1.set(xlabel = 'Month', ylabel = 'Bookings')   
ax1.set_xticklabels(months)
ax2.set(xlabel = 'Month', ylabel = 'Bookings')   
ax2.set_xticklabels(months)
ax1.set_title('Absoulute Number of Bookings', y=1.03, fontsize=17)   
ax2.set_title('Conversion Rate', y=1.03, fontsize=17)   
ax1.get_legend().remove()   
ax2.legend(loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(1.25, 0.85), ncol=1)   
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.2)
```